# how to put an api gateway to work through a certain path in cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

so I have an api gateway that's working through a certain domain,

let's call it https://api-something.com, with a proxy authenticator

and a cloudfront destribution that's working on a different domain

https://somethingelse.com, with a proxy authenticator as well

the proxy authenticator can't send cookies through different origins

so I was thinking of combining both and have the api gateway work through a certain path in cloudfront, but for some reason the api gateway just doesn't show up when trying to add it as a domain origin,

[image]

I'm looking for any solution either to the original issue or why I can't use the api gateway as the domain origin.

Answer (score 0):

The origin dropdown could be empty because (1) the API Gateway endpoint is under a different AWS account id, or (2) CloudFront could not fetch a list of your API Gateway origins. You can always manually input the URL to your API Gateway application as the origin endpoint for CloudFront.

A challenge with this setup is the custom domain. If CloudFront receives requests for `somethingelse.com`, how will it send a `Host` header to your API Gateway origin that is expecting a value of `api-something.com`?

Your simplest option is to stop using the custom domain on API Gateway, and put the API Gateway origin endpoint (`*.amazonaws.com`) behind CloudFront.